# Google Maps V2 crashes

Tags: android, google-maps

Everything works fine til I update my android tools rev 22.3, android sdk platform tools rev 19.0.1, android support library rev 19.0.1, google play services rev 15.

Now whenever I access my activity with google maps, my app crashes. LogCat:

```
02-24 21:18:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(23474): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 21:18:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(23474): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{packagename}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-24 21:18:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(23474):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
02-24 21:18:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(23474):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
02-24 21:18:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(23474):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
02-24 21:18:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(23474):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
02-24 21:18:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(23474):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
02-24 21:18:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(23474):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
02-24 21:18:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(23474):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
02-24 21:18:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(23474):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 21:18:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(23474):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-24 21:18:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(23474):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
02-24 21:18:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(23474):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-24 21:18:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(23474):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 21:18:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(23474): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-24 21:18:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(23474):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
02-24 21:18:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(23474):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
02-24 21:18:55.336: E/AndroidRuntime(23474):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
```

**Manifest:**

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <permission
        android:name="packagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="packagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

        <activity android:name="packagename.balona.MapDetail" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="key" />

// I add these based on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724113/google-play-services-update
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

**xml:**

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

**OnCreate google map activity:**

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            googleMap = fm.getMap();

            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
```

It's working fine until I updated what I've said above in Android SDK Manager. What should I do? Please help. Should I reinstall my eclipse adt?

Answer (score 1):

Once you try to add clean the project and refresh and even try to restart your virtual device..

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when I didn't add playServices project as dependency to my project in build properties.

Please look on [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html).

But also good think is to look in android sdk in addons folder for the sample project of play services and add it simply as dependency to your project.

Add that project as dependency to yours
**sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib**

Comment: Yes but I mean that you should add project and library. Project(play-services) should be added as dependency project for yours.

Comment: Add that project as build dependecy sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\

Comment: Yes they're already in my app's android private libraries and android dependencies

Comment: Ok, so I have no clue what else it might be.