# checking the availability of Google Play services on a device

Tags: android, google-play-services

i am trying to check the availability of Google Play services on a device. but the app is crashing on start up. the app runs without the servicesOK() method, and i have imported the google play services into my project.. i'm not sure, or understand, why the app is crashing.

here is my MainActivity.java (the only code in the app so far):

```
package com.example.gmapsapp;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int GPS_EERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(servicesOK()){
              Toast.makeText(this,  "message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public boolean servicesOK(){

    int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if(isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        return true;
    }
    else if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)){
        Dialog dialog = 
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, 
                         this, GPS_EERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this,  "Cannot Connect to to Google Play services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: So what is the stack trace?

Comment: It's likely something you're missing in your AndroidManfest.xml -- please post what you have in the Manifest as well as any error information (e.g. logcat)

Comment: Maybe duplicated from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724113/google-play-services-update.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed. i was missing the following code from the manifest file:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```