# Unable to start activity in inner class and activity class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, intellij-idea, google-maps-android-api-2

I've got an android project from another developer. He can launch this project on his machine successfully, but  when I try to launch  it on my machine, I've got this exception when application trying load map in a fragment. The logcat with exception:

```
09-29 07:37:50.298    2442-2442/nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime/nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.fragment.MapFragment$InnerActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2054)
        at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
        at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
        at nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.fragment.MapFragment.onCreate(MapFragment.java:132)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1477)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:893)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:651)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
        at nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.fragment.MapFragmen
09-29 07:42:50.399    2442-2442/nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2442 SIG: 9
```

Android manifest:

```
android:versionCode="7"
android:versionName="1.3" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<permission
    android:name="nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name="nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.CoffeetimeApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:description="@string/app_desc"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_logo57"
    android:label="Coffeetime TISH Limited"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDMx6IbAJEWnHuKv_yv4Pkwgx_U1mF2Qkc" />
    <!--Debug: AIzaSyDMx6IbAJEWnHuKv_yv4Pkwgx_U1mF2Qkc-->
    <!--Live: AIzaSyCnNpNptAzaBdtF9GOAVw-POo1gt2Tsw-Q-->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.versionCode"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name="nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppMainTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.PlaceActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_place"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.ForgotPasswordActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_forgot_password"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.CVCInfoActivity"
        android:label="@string/cvc_text_header"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.CategoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_category"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.ProductActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_product"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.CategoryActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.CheckoutActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_checkout"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.PlaceActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.TopupActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_topup"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.RegisterCardActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register_card"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.StoreMapActivity"
        android:label="@string/store_map_title_activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.AuthActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_auth"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.VersionInfoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_version"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.AuthActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.TermsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_terms"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="launch.TermsActivity" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.AuthActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
     android:name="nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.fragment.MapFragment$InnerActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LogoutActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_logout"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LikeUsOnFacebookActivity"
        android:label="Like Us On Facebook Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />     
</application>
```

The code of fragment with map(MapFragment):

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements LocationListener {
private static GoogleMap mapView;
private static final String MAP_ACTIVITY_ID = "map-activity";
private static final String ACTIVITY_MANAGER_BUNDLE_KEY = "activity-manager-bundle-key";
private LocalActivityManager localActivityManager;
private LocationManager locationManager = null;
private Window window;
private ProgressDialog dialog = null;
private String bestProvider = null;
private Criteria criteria = null;
private String keyword = "";
private Place[] places;
private HashMap<String, Place> currentPlaces;
private AsyncTask<Object, Object, CallResult<List<Place>>> location_task;
public static class InnerActivity extends
        FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_map);
        mapView = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapv2)).getMap();            
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = window.getDecorView();
    keyword = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSearchString();
    locationManager = (LocationManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(
            Activity.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (locationManager == null) {
        DialogUtil.showAlert(view.getContext(),
                "Sorry, you do not seem to have GPS!");
        return null;
    }
    if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    criteria = new Criteria();
    bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    ((ViewGroup) window.getDecorView().getParent()).removeAllViews();
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBundle(ACTIVITY_MANAGER_BUNDLE_KEY,
            localActivityManager.saveInstanceState());
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = null;
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        bundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(ACTIVITY_MANAGER_BUNDLE_KEY);
    }
    localActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(getActivity(), true);
    localActivityManager.dispatchCreate(bundle);
    window = localActivityManager.startActivity(MAP_ACTIVITY_ID,
            new Intent(getActivity(), InnerActivity.class));
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    localActivityManager.dispatchResume();
    places = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getPlaces();
    location_task = null;
    if (places == null) {
        AsyncTask<Object, Object, Location> task = new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Location>() {
            @Override
            protected Location doInBackground(Object... params) {
                return locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Location result) {
                onLocationChanged(result);
            }
        };
        task.execute();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 1000 * 60 * 5,
                25, this);
    } else {
        setUpMapview(places);
    }
}
private void setUpMapview(Place[] places) {
    // List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable openPlace = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.opened);
    Drawable closedPlace = this.getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.closed);
    List<GeoPoint> items = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
    currentPlaces = new HashMap<String, Place>();
    mapView.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker coffe) {
            if (currentPlaces != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        PlaceActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("place",
                        currentPlaces.get(coffe.getTitle()));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
    for (Place place : places) {
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (place.getLatitude()),
                (int) (place.getLongitude()));
        items.add(point);
        Marker placeMarker = mapView
                .addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(
                                new LatLng(place.getLatitude(), place
                                        .getLongitude()))
                        .title(place.getName())
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(place
                                .isOpen() ? R.drawable.opened
                                : R.drawable.closed)));

        currentPlaces.put(place.getName(), place);
        // itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        // mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
    }
    MapUtils.animateToCenter(mapView, items, false);
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    localActivityManager.dispatchPause(getActivity().isFinishing());
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    localActivityManager.dispatchStop();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    localActivityManager.dispatchDestroy(getActivity().isFinishing());
}
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    localActivityManager = null;
}
private class DialogOverlay extends SimpleItemizedOverlay {
    public DialogOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, MapView mapView) {
        super(defaultMarker, mapView);
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index, OverlayItem item) {
        /*
         * Intent intent = new Intent(mapView.getContext(),
         * PlaceActivity.class); intent.putExtra("place",
         * ((DialogOverlayItem)item).getCurrentPlace());
         * startActivity(intent);
         */
        return true;
    }
}
private class DialogOverlayItem extends OverlayItem {

    private Place currentPlace;

    public DialogOverlayItem(GeoPoint point, String title, String snippet,
            Place place) {
        super(point, title, snippet);
        setCurrentPlace(place);
    }
    private Place getCurrentPlace() {
        return currentPlace;
    }
    private void setCurrentPlace(Place currentPlace) {
        this.currentPlace = currentPlace;
    }
}
```

}

fragment_map.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/mapv2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {
private ListView mDrawerList;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
CustomViewPager mViewPager;
private Place[] places;
private String keyword = "";
private boolean checkedOut;
public Place[] getPlaces() {
    return places;
}
public void setPlaces(Place[] places) {
    this.places = places;
}
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new MyFavoritesFragment();
        case 1:
            return new NearMeFragment();
        case 2:
            return new MapFragment();
        case 3:
            return new HistoryFragment(checkedOut);
        case 4:
            return new WalletFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
    public int getPageIcon(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return R.drawable.icon_fav;
            case 1:
                return R.drawable.icon_near;
            case 2:
                return R.drawable.icon_map;
            case 3:
                return R.drawable.icon_hist;
            case 4:
                return R.drawable.icon_wallet;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_activity_my_favorites).toUpperCase();
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_activity_near_me).toUpperCase();
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_activity_map).toUpperCase();
        case 3:
            return getString(R.string.title_activity_history).toUpperCase();
        case 4:
            return getString(R.string.title_activity_wallet).toUpperCase();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

This application also has another Activity with map , and the app is crashing on it too. The logcat:

```
09-29 08:33:50.559    2604-2604/nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime/nz.co.tish.android.coffeetime.StoreMapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4242000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.ex(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
```

StoreMapActivity:

```
public class StoreMapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private Place place = null;
private GoogleMap mapView;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        onBackPressed();
        return (true);
    }

    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    setContentView(R.layout.store_map_activity);
    mapView = (GoogleMap) ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.store_mapv2)).getMap();

    Serializable placeSer = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("place");
    if (placeSer == null
            || !Place.class.isAssignableFrom(placeSer.getClass())) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        return;
    }

    place = (Place) placeSer;
    setUpMapview();
    /*List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable openPlace = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.opened);
    Drawable closedPlace = this.getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.closed);
    List<GeoPoint> items = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
    SimpleItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new SimpleItemizedOverlay(
            place.isOpen() ? openPlace : closedPlace, mapView);

    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
            (int) (place.getLatitude() * Const.GEOPOINT_CONST),
            (int) (place.getLongitude() * Const.GEOPOINT_CONST));
    items.add(point);
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, place.getName(), "");

    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

    // MapUtils.animateToCenter(mapView, items, true);*/
}

private void setUpMapview() {

Drawable openPlace = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.opened);
Drawable closedPlace = this.getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.closed);
List<GeoPoint> items = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
mapView.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker coffe) {
            if (place != null) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(StoreMapActivity.this,
                        PlaceActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("place", place);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    });

GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (place.getLatitude()),(int)(place.getLongitude()));
items.add(point);
Marker placeMarker = mapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                            new LatLng(place.getLatitude(), place.getLongitude()))
                    .title(place.getName())
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(place
                            .isOpen() ? R.drawable.opened
                            : R.drawable.closed)));

MapUtils.animateToCenter(mapView, items, false);

}
```

}

store_map_activity.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/store_mapv2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

When I commented the code initializing the maps on these parts of application, it will start working normally.

Comment: what is there in line no 17 xml file fragment_map?

Comment: 17 line ->
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/mapv2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

Comment: is thr semicolon after xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" line

Comment: check this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735507/google-play-services-v13-error-meta-data-in-androidmanifest?answertab=active#tab-top) for ur issue

Comment: You've posted far too much code here, please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the section about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that you have added the exceptions to your proguard configuration file. How and what to add is explained in [Setting up Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

Answer (score 0):

For the first, change your fragment from this:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/mapv2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

to this:

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

the main difference in this case is

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

to this:

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

For the second: add the following to the end of your manifest (but beforde the end-tag application!)

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

In your code you can ask for the service with the following:

```
// check status
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

try {
    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) 
    {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices).show();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error: ", + e);
}
```