# Google Drive, meta-data tag in app's AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-drive-realtime-api

I used the Google Drive API to transfer files on device to Google Drive, but following error occurred after updated to new version.(android 4.4)

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist. You must have the following declaration within the -application- element: meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Added following code in `AndroidManifest.xml`

> meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4030500" />

After modifying AndroidManifest.xml and clicking the file transfer button, `Play Store` will be launched and the`Google Play Service` app page will be displayed.

I don't know, what's wrong?

Comment: Terribly sorry, but StackOverflow is only available in English.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not fully in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Drive API new version (drive-v2r106lv1.15.0-rc)

Comment: I update Drive-Api new version and I append in AndroidManifest.xml file - <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4030500" /> <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

Answer (score -3):

This is google-play-service.jar revision mismatch problem. Downgrade google-play-server revision 13 under.

http://www.mediafire.com/download/5w6x1u2xmpgq8fy/google-play-services.jar

Comment: No, this is not how you solve the problem. Please don't supply unverified questionable links to what is an official Google jar. The correct way to solve this is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723811/after-google-play-service-update-to-version-13-i-got-an-error

Comment: Thank you, but problem is unresolved. Do you know, where is download site official google-play-services.jar revision 13 under file

Comment: I do not find method of download google-play-services.jar revision 12 file. please tell me this method.

Comment: You do that through the Android Tools SDK Manager

Comment: There is no way from 'revision 13' to 'revision 12' in Android Tools SDK Manager.

Comment: What's wrong with the "Google Play services for Froyo" Revision 12 ? In any case, you should be able to use the rev13 according to the link I gave you. You should seriously look into solve that problem of yours first.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try with your recommend.

Comment: BTW, since you haven't written your question in English, I can't tell for sure, but if you have entered that line in your manifest file, it's wrong. Again, see the link I gave you.

Comment: I am sorry, I'm not fluent written english.

Comment: After google-play-services new version update, Google Drive API occur problem.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist. You must have the following declaration within the <application> element: <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: I append AndroidManifest.xml file, <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4030500" />

Comment: But, problem is unresolved.

Comment: I try https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android

Comment: <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: How fix ==> Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version')

Comment: new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909493/meta-data-tag-in-apps-androidmanifset-xml-for-drive-api

Comment: Thank you, After update Drive Api new version, My problem is solved.