# android google map v.2 : android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #739: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I found similar topics in stackoverflow but it didn't help for me. I want to show map, but when i run it, it return force close. Here are the codes :

```
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
```

this is my layout :

```
   <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

this is my manifest :

```
   <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY_API_KEY" />


    </application>
```

this my logcat :

```
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{id.go.kpp.aplikasipupi/id.go.kpp.aplikasipupi.kartu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #739: Error inflating class fragment
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #739: Error inflating class fragment
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:306)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1912)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at id.go.kpp.aplikasipupi.kartu.onCreate(kartu.java:100)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5163)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    ... 11 more
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.cE(Unknown Source)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4813)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
11-13 16:03:10.652: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    ... 24 more
```

i don't know why it still error, i hope somebody can help me to solve my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [After Google Play Service update to version 13 I got an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723811/after-google-play-service-update-to-version-13-i-got-an-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logcat is clear

You need to add the below to manifest file

```
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_the_google_play_services_version_to_your_apps_manifest

Edit your application's AndroidManifest.xml file, and add the following declaration within the `<application>` element. This embeds the version of Google Play services that the app was compiled with.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same exception as well, but I figured out for Google API v2 to work, you must include these permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
```

I hope this will help you guys.

P.S I used these permissions for adding a simple map in my app. There are certain other permissions which [this link](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw) suggests as well.