# Forceclose occuring while opening the application

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-fragmentactivity

What happened is i changed my project from one machine to another. When i am running my app from the first machine it is running successfully but the same application gives a forceclose while starting the app.

My project is using two libraries
1. ActionBarSherlock library
2. GooglePlayService Library

The error log i am getting is given below.

```
Failed to inflate
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
at                 com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:133)
at     com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:261)
at com.qxtapp.QxtHome.onCreate(QxtHome.java:161)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.cE(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
... 23 more
```

If anybody need any clarification on my problem please ask. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949420/android-google-map-v-2-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-73/19949560#19949560. the log is clear and also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723811/after-google-play-service-update-to-version-13-i-got-an-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added This in manifest file and worked fine.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```