# Google Maps v2 Error inflating XML

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, android-fragments

I know this has been asked before, but I couldn't find any solutions there.

I tried to include a google map in my android application, but it keeps crashing:

```
11-14 14:58:51.864: D/dalvikvm(1604): Late-enabling CheckJNI
11-14 14:58:51.914: D/AndroidRuntime(1604): Shutting down VM
11-14 14:58:51.914: W/dalvikvm(1604): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f7cb90)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604): Process: com.example.testmaps, PID: 1604
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testmaps/com.example.testmaps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at com.example.testmaps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     ... 11 more
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.cE(Unknown Source)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4784)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
11-14 14:58:51.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1604):     ... 20 more
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testmaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />



    <permission
    android:name="com.example.testmaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.testmaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testmaps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyAJPOrFWSi-z9ME1xbevn-Kl7QOYA1h0iE" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_my_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.testmaps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_map);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I tried to change it to FragmentActivity as well, but without any luck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949420/android-google-map-v-2-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-73/19949560#19949560. and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723811/after-google-play-service-update-to-version-13-i-got-an-error

Comment: @Raghunandan thankyou..  I hadn't worked with play service 13 yet. :). Thank you for saving stackoverflow from a useless answer from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error in your log-cat states, you need to add the following `meta-data` tag:

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

inside the application tag in your `Manifest` file, it's a new requirement added from the last revision 13 update to `google-play-services`.