# Map Fragment not working in Android4.4 kitkat

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-4.4-kitkat

I am facing a wierd problem in Android kitkat. I am not able to use map fragments(support map fragment too). I used the following code:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1" />
```

My application works in api level 18(Jellybean) but when compiled with kitkat it gives the following error: Error inflating class fragment!

Logcat output:

```
11-14 07:12:12.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

11-14 07:12:12.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1068): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #96: Error inflating class fragment

11-14 07:12:12.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)

11-14 07:12:12.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)

11-14 07:12:12.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)

11-14 07:12:12.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)

11-14 07:12:12.039: E/AndroidRuntime(1068):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
```

Comment: what is binary XML file line #96?

Comment: I need to support eclair too so i am using supportmapfragment

Comment: Post full stacktrace. There should be a "caused by" exception below what you're showing (and paste it as text, not as image).

Comment: it is the part in my layout where i start my fragment i have view flipper above it

Comment: @Andru my fragment starts at line 96

Comment: @laalto I have updated my question I couldn't format my logcat appropriately sorry for that

Comment: Without seeing the "caused by" exception below the InflateException in  the stack trace, there's only wild guesses to help you.

Comment: Often when there are issues involving updates and SupportFragments it means your support library may need updated or may not be on the build path correctly. Try using "Add Support Library.." or checking your build path.

Comment: instead of fragment, use SupportMapFragment

Comment: @SathMK I am using support map fragment

Comment: possible duplicate of [After Google Play Service update to version 13 I got an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723811/after-google-play-service-update-to-version-13-i-got-an-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding the following line to the manifest file as a direct element of the application tag this was probably enforced after the new google play services was launched:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Also a note to fellow developers make sure you extend your activity with FragmentActivity.

Answer (score 2):

on nexus 5 device there are incompatible support and play services libraries, if you are using them in your project (either in `libs` for support-v4 or project libraries for the others) you can delete the related `<uses-library ... />` tags from `AndroidManifest.xml` since the necessary bytecode should already be included in your app.
Doing this fixed the problem for me: I was actually using the fragment programmatically and getting a "caused by":

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation

Comment: i am getting android.view.inflateexception at the point where my fragments start