# android - Run time error

Tags: android, google-maps

These are the errors I got while I tried to do Google maps in android using apiV2.
Please help me.

```
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps/com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     ... 11 more
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.cE(Unknown Source)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
11-20 15:44:39.835: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     ... 21 more
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [After Google Play Service update to version 13 I got an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723811/after-google-play-service-update-to-version-13-i-got-an-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that from the log you posted:

> The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the
>   right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the
>   following declaration within the  element:

Follow step by step google documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#install_and_configure_the_google_play_services_sdk)

OR that tutorial [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/). Of course there are too many documentations online for google maps api usage!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run you map code in the UIThread. It may possible that it doesnot allow to run on main thread