# force close when trying to display google map fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

When I try an launch an activity with a google map fragment I get this error:

```
12-10 17:45:26.395    4282-4282/com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro/com.example.beerportfoliopro.BreweryMap}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2517)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2574)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1413)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:339)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1944)
            at com.example.beerportfoliopro.BreweryMap.onCreate(BreweryMap.java:40)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5195)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2473)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2574)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1413)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.cE(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4807)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:339)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1944)
            at com.example.beerportfoliopro.BreweryMap.onCreate(BreweryMap.java:40)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5195)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2473)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2574)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1413)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-10 17:45:26.405  24060-24091/system_process E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ App crashed! Process: com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro
12-10 17:45:26.405  24060-24091/system_process E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ App crashed! Package: com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro v23 (3.1)
12-10 17:45:26.405  24060-24091/system_process E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ Application Label: BeerPortfolio Pro
```

My xml file for the activity is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

and my class code is:

```
public class BreweryMap extends ActionbarMenu {

    BeerData e;
    private GoogleMap map;

    //get beer details from bundle
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_brewerymap);

        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();




    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);

        return true;
    }





}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [After Google Play Service update to version 13 I got an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723811/after-google-play-service-update-to-version-13-i-got-an-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it clearly explained in stack trace:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's
 AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but 
 found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> \
 element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

just add

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

to your Manifest.