# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: error inflating class fragment / from an emulator

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to make a simple map and debugging it in an emulator. I was wondering where is my mistake and how can I correct it.

Here is: Logcat:

```
12-12 15:32:28.310: D/dalvikvm(879): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
12-12 15:32:30.070: D/AndroidRuntime(879): Shutting down VM
12-12 15:32:30.070: W/dalvikvm(879): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3abdb90)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879): Process: com.exemple.mysecondapp, PID: 879
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.exemple.mysecondapp/com.exemple.mysecondapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.exemple.mysecondapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  ... 11 more
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.cE(Unknown Source)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
12-12 15:32:30.150: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  ... 20 more
12-12 15:34:25.171: I/Process(879): Sending signal. PID: 879 SIG: 9
```

Main class:

```
package com.exemple.mysecondapp;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private GoogleMap gm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        }
        else {
            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/map"
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

app manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.exemple.mysecondapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.exemple.mysecondapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps" />


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AN API KEY"/>
    </application>    
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


<permission
    android:name="com.exemple.mysecondapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.exemple.mysecondapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```

I passed many hours on this and to date no valid answer. Thank you to anyone who answers this question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723811/after-google-play-service-update-to-version-13-i-got-an-error

Comment: Ok, I found the error. The meta-data is not at the right place in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

```
The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.
```

You should install google play services in emulator (based on Android 4.2.2 or higher)

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: I did that. The second meta-data was not in the right place. Now I get the Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above. Which I do not understand since I put it in there. Plus it should be supported by the AVD.