# Google map I have get error logcat

Tags: android, eclipse, api

I have completely signed my  sha1 and sign with google apis, but I got this error:

```
 01-28 13:44:37.081: D/dalvikvm(12155): Late-enabling CheckJNI 01-28
 13:44:37.211: D/ActivityThread(12155): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
 01-28 13:44:37.211: D/ActivityThread(12155):
 setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608 01-28 13:44:37.211:
 D/ActivityThread(12155): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152 01-28
 13:44:37.481: D/AndroidRuntime(12155): Shutting down VM 01-28
 13:44:37.481: W/dalvikvm(12155): threadid=1: thread exiting with
 uncaught exception (group=0x40e0c438) 01-28 13:44:37.481:
 E/AndroidRuntime(12155): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 01-28 13:44:37.481:
 E/AndroidRuntime(12155): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
 activity
 ComponentInfo{com.example.mapsv2/googleplaymap.com.org.ClustersAreListsActivity}:
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error
 inflating class fragment 01-28 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):
    at
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
 01-28 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
 01-28 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143) 01-28
 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):     at
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
 01-28 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):   at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 01-28
 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):     at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 01-28 13:44:37.481:
 E/AndroidRuntime(12155):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960) 01-28
 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):     at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-28
 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):     at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 01-28 13:44:37.481:
 E/AndroidRuntime(12155):   at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
 01-28 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):   at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 01-28
 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):     at
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 01-28 13:44:37.481:
 E/AndroidRuntime(12155): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
 Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment 01-28
 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):     at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
 01-28 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):   at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752) 01-28
 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):     at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 01-28
 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):     at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 01-28
 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):     at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 01-28
 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):     at
 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:318)
  01-28 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):  at
 android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1925) 01-28
 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155): at
    googleplaymap.com.org.ClustersAreListsActivity.onCreate(ClustersAreListsActivity.java:82)
 01-28 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):   at
 android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203) 01-28
 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):     at
 android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
 01-28 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
 01-28 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):   ... 11 more 01-28
 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155): Caused by:
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's
 AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4132500
 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the
 <application> element:     <meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 01-28
 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):     at
 com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
 01-28 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155): at
  com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown
 Source) 01-28 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):   at
       com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source) 01-28
 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):     at
 com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source) 01-28
 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):     at
 com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
 01-28 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):   at
 com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.eb(Unknown Source)
 01-28 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):   at
 com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
 01-28 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):   at
 com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source) 01-28 13:44:37.481:
 E/AndroidRuntime(12155):   at
 com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source) 01-28
 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):     at
 com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown
 Source) 01-28 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):   at
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:284)
 01-28 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):   at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
 01-28 13:44:37.481: E/AndroidRuntime(12155):   ... 21 more
```

Comment: here is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21407987/1012284

Comment: unfortunately  gmap has stopped in my device display

Comment: possible duplicate of [unfortunately my maps has stopped working. Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407876/unfortunately-my-maps-has-stopped-working-android)

Comment: 4132500 which integer value is this

Comment: it mean this is not correct way                             <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
     android:value="my api keys are there " />

Comment: also same error log cat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

///you need to add this line also in your manifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
           android:value="your api keys "/>          

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

//and you need to add this below line in your values folder in string.xml or integer.xml

```
 <integer name="google_play_services_version">4132500</integer>
```

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode the version, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19879844/adding-google-play-services-version-to-your-apps-manifest).

Comment: @MártonMolnár Yes you are right. But "When you link properly Google-play-services library"  When I do properly I am not getting.

Comment: Thanks allot great u are so great i gating this problem before 2 or 3 days finally u have tell me this solution to get correct answer for this problem i have ask before many of persons but no buddy reply correct  answer u are such great knowledge <Great man >