# Map not getting displayed

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to load a map .The map elements like zoom,location etc are loaded however the map isn't displayed

I have added the api key and other stuffs needed for the map.

I get the logcat as :`The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.`

Below is my manifest Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.blah.blahh"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

     <permission android:name="com.xxx.xxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
        .
        .
        .

                </activity>

         <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
            />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaXXXxXXXXXXXXXX7mSf-THX" />   

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any thoughts regarding this are welcome

Comment: you have not referenced google play services library project or your device does not have google play services installed

Comment: Follow the official tutorial from google exactly.

Comment: @Raghunandan My device has google play services installed

Comment: I found the same issue but when i signed my apk then issue is solved

Comment: @MD I had tried a small app only for testing map and it worked.I use the same code in my present app it fails, Any idea about it?

Comment: I added poogle play version in my package http://stackoverflow.com/a/21427839/1012284. I think you are trying to get the version from the google-play lib project. Just add the resourse in your project dimen.xml,

Comment: as per my opinion u should remove `google_play_lib library` from u r project and update first and then add this library again and clean built u r project. i m doing same and it's working

Answer (score 3):

include this in manifest

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Please make sure you have added google play store library project with your project.

Also make sure you have added the map api key corresponding to  your app signature

Comment: I have add it .I will post my xml

Comment: @Abhilash are you sure your api key is corresponding to ur app keystore?

Answer (score 0):

The package name provided to get API key may be changed. Make sure that package name used  correct