# Google Maps Android API V2 showing current location with marker(where am i in google android maps api v2)

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I am beginner in android , i am developing an android app for displaying my current location on google maps.But as i run my application it display a message "Unfortunately stopped" on emulator as well as physical device.
i am attaching my code .plz have a look.
pls help me ....i am not able to resolve this

thanks

***MainActivity.java***

package com.example.mapp;

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMyLocationChangeListener {
GoogleMap googlemap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        int status=GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
        {
            int requestCode=10;
            Dialog dialog=GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status,this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();
        }
        else
        {
            SupportMapFragment fm = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
                    googlemap=fm.getMap();
                    googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    googlemap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
        }
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

    TextView tvLocation=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    double latitude=location.getLatitude();
    double longitude=location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng=new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    googlemap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    googlemap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    tvLocation.setText("Latitude:"+latitude+",Longitude:"+longitude);
}


}
```

***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <permission android:name="com.example.mapp.permission.MAP_RECIEVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapp.permission.MAP_RECIEVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!-- External storage for caching. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY_API_KEY" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

***activity_main.xml***

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <fragment

        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textview1"

       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post the stack trace. add a metag tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723811/after-google-play-service-update-to-version-13-i-got-an-error

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code inside application tag

```
<meta-data 
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score -1):

I know to show your current location, you must use a real device

Comment: This is not an answer.