# null pointer exception in GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps

I am getting a NullPointerException at the time of running the below code.I doesn't know how to solve these.

**StackTrace:**

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(1118): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118): Process: info.androidhive.googlemapsv2, PID: 1118
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.googlemapsv2/info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    E/AndroidRuntime(1118):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    ... 11 more
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4452000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.t(Unknown Source)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.B(Unknown Source)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.A(Unknown Source)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.ip(Unknown Source)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4785)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    ... 21 more
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

            // Changing map type
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);


            // Showing / hiding your current location
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable zooming controls
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

            // Enable / Disable my location button
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable Compass icon
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable Rotate gesture
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable zooming functionality
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

            double latitude = 17.385044;
            double longitude = 78.486671;

            // lets place some 10 random markers
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                // random latitude and logitude
                double[] randomLocation = createRandLocation(latitude,
                        longitude);

                // Adding a marker
                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(randomLocation[0], randomLocation[1]))
                        .title("Hello Maps " + i);

                Log.e("Random", "> " + randomLocation[0] + ", "
                        + randomLocation[1]);

                // changing marker color
                if (i == 0)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
                if (i == 1)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
                if (i == 2)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN));
                if (i == 3)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                if (i == 4)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
                if (i == 5)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
                if (i == 6)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                if (i == 7)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));
                if (i == 8)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET));
                if (i == 9)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));

                googleMap.addMarker(marker);

                // Move the camera to last position with a zoom level
                if (i == 9) {
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(randomLocation[0],
                                    randomLocation[1])).zoom(15).build();

                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

    /**
     * function to load map If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * creating random postion around a location for testing purpose only
     */
    private double[] createRandLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {

        return new double[] { latitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
                longitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
                150 + ((Math.random() - 0.5) * 10) };
    }
}
```

**Maifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <!-- Requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">


        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Goolge API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyB2p7rsFLCuYmjA8SnRsIZfjWugwgh4wtU" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am getting NullPointerException. I doesn't know how to get rid of errors.Anybody know how to solve these.Thank You.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723811/after-google-play-service-update-to-version-13-i-got-an-error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your logcat clearly said

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4452000 but found 0.  You must    have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
 E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.t(Unknown Source)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.B(Unknown Source)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1118):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.A(Unkno
```

You need to add google play services version as `<meta-data>` tag under `<application>` tag in your `manifest.xml`

```
  <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: still the error occurred after changing these.Check my edited post.

Comment: @Stephen check your google play services propely configure or not.