# Android project code run problems

Tags: android, eclipse

Good evening. 
I need your help. 
I try to run the following plan but my export errors below.
Good evening. 
I need your help. 
I try to run the following plan but my export errors below.
CatLog:

```
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{abw.abw.abw/abw.abw.abw.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class fragment
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class fragment
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at abw.abw.abw.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    ... 11 more
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 6171000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.E(Unknown Source)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.T(Unknown Source)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.S(Unknown Source)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.mA(Unknown Source)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2158)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
12-18 20:40:30.183: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    ... 21 more
```

MainActivity.java

```
package abw.abw.abw;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap map;
    RadioButton rbDriving;
    RadioButton rbBiCycling;
    RadioButton rbWalking;
    RadioGroup rgModes;
    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
    int mMode=0;
    final int MODE_DRIVING=0;
    final int MODE_BICYCLING=1;
    final int MODE_WALKING=2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Getting reference to rb_driving
        rbDriving = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb_driving);

        // Getting reference to rb_bicylcing
        rbBiCycling = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb_bicycling);

        // Getting reference to rb_walking
        rbWalking = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb_walking);

        // Getting Reference to rg_modes
        rgModes = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg_modes);

        rgModes.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
                if(markerPoints.size() >= 2){
                    LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
                    LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

                    // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                    String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                    downloadTask.execute(url);
                }
            }
        });

        // Initializing
        markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
        map = fm.getMap();

        // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Setting onclick event listener for the map
        map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                // Already two locations
                if(markerPoints.size()>1){
                    markerPoints.clear();
                    map.clear();
                }

                // Adding new item to the ArrayList
                markerPoints.add(point);

                // Draws Start and Stop markers on the Google Map
                drawStartStopMarkers();

                // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
                if(markerPoints.size() >= 2){
                    LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
                    LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

                    // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                    String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                    downloadTask.execute(url);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Drawing Start and Stop locations
    private void drawStartStopMarkers(){

        for(int i=0;i<markerPoints.size();i++){

            // Creating MarkerOptions
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position of the marker
            options.position(markerPoints.get(i) );

            /**
            * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
            * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
            */
            if(i==0){
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            }else if(i==1){
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            }

            // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
            map.addMarker(options);
        }
    }
    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Travelling Mode
        String mode = "mode=driving";

        if(rbDriving.isChecked()){
            mode = "mode=driving";
            mMode = 0 ;
        }else if(rbBiCycling.isChecked()){
            mode = "mode=bicycling";
            mMode = 1;
        }else if(rbWalking.isChecked()){
            mode = "mode=walking";
            mMode = 2;
        }

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor+"&"+mode;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

        return url;
    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try{
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Traversing through all the routes
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                    HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(2);

                // Changing the color polyline according to the mode
                if(mMode==MODE_DRIVING)
                    lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
                else if(mMode==MODE_BICYCLING)
                    lineOptions.color(Color.GREEN);
                else if(mMode==MODE_WALKING)
                    lineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
            }

            if(result.size()<1){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Points", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

DirectionsJSONParser.java

```js
package abw.abw.abw;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class DirectionsJSONParser {

    /** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude */
    public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>() ;
        JSONArray jRoutes = null;
        JSONArray jLegs = null;
        JSONArray jSteps = null;

        try {

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing all routes */
            for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
                jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                    jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                            path.add(hm);
                        }
                    }
                    routes.add(path);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){
        }
        return routes;
    }

    /**
    * Method to decode polyline points
    * Courtesy : jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
    * */
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                        (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }
        return poly;
    }
}
```

Manifest

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="abw.abw.abw"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <permission
        android:name="abw.abw.abw.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="abw.abw.abw.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="abw.abw.abw.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBjtHbFgMQ6S7JF9632aPTw7wNHv_D24Bo"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg_modes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rb_driving"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/str_rb_driving"
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rb_bicycling"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/str_rb_bicycling" />

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rb_walking"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/str_rb_walking" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/rg_modes"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you read? Exception is self explanatory...

Comment: possible duplicate of [After Google Play Service update to version 13 I got an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723811/after-google-play-service-update-to-version-13-i-got-an-error)

Comment: hi. yes i can... i reading After Google Play Service update to version 13 I got an error. thanks my. friend :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following declaration within the `<application>` element and before `<activity>` element in your Android Manifest file:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: add but again exports errors `12-18 23:01:55.393: E/AndroidRuntime(14790): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 23:01:55.393: E/AndroidRuntime(14790): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{abw.abw.abw/abw.abw.abw.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class fragment

.............................
12-18 23:01:55.393: E/AndroidRuntime(14790):  ... 21 more
`

Comment: Have you imported Fragment from the Android Support Library?